# filter elements in complex list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this data frame

```
df1 = [('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'tbeli': 1}), ('g', {'mos': 1}), ('g', {'esc': 1})]
```

I want it like this

```
df2=[('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'tbeli': 1})]

df3=[('g', {'mos': 1}), ('g', {'esc': 1})]
```

I tried this code

```
L1 = [year for (title, year) in (sorted(df1.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))]
```

Comment: are the items grouped? you could use `itertools.groupby`

Comment: If one of the below solutions solved your problem, please consider accepting (green tick on left), or feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

One way of filtering the list is to split it into sublists indexed by 'f' or 'g':

```
from collections import defaultdict

df1 = [('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'tbeli': 1}), ('g', {'mos': 1}), ('g', {'esc': 1})]

df = defaultdict(list)

for item in df1:
    df[item[0]].append(item)

df2 = df['f']
df3 = df['g']

print(df2)
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
[('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'tbeli': 1})]
[('g', {'mos': 1}), ('g', {'esc': 1})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

df1 = [('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'tbeli': 1}), ('g', {'mos': 1}), ('g', {'esc': 1})]

splitted = [list(v) for k, v in groupby(df1, key = lambda x: x[0])]
print(splitted)
```

---

This yields

```
[[('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'tbeli': 1})], [('g', {'mos': 1}), ('g', {'esc': 1})]]
```

You can access the individual items via `splitted[0]` afterwards but it only works, when the data has been sorted before.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary for a variable number of variables.

The efficient way is via `collections.defaultdict`, as shown in [@quamrana's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49873230/9209546), but this is also possible via a list comprehension within a dictionary comprehension.

```
df1 = [('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'tbeli': 1}), ('g', {'mos': 1}), ('g', {'esc': 1})]

res = {i: [x for x in df1 if x[0]==i] for i, j in df1}

# {'f': [('f', {'abe': 1}), ('f', {'tbeli': 1})],
#  'g': [('g', {'mos': 1}), ('g', {'esc': 1})]}
```